# Display Hold/Closed status in Edit review queue

Tags: feature-request

This previous Meta question, [Warn when approving edits for questions on hold](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8076/warn-when-approving-edits-for-questions-on-hold), deals with not approving edits to on-hold questions that don't solve the hold issue.  It proposed a warning to alert the reviewer.

The issue is to not waste reviewers' time by dumping the question into the reopen queue when the close issue has not been addressed.  The question is also bumped on the main page (reducing attention for new questions), even though readers are still unable to answer it.

The problem is not limited to approving edits, it also applies to improving on them.  On several occasions, I've seen an edit that contained some glaring error, or overlooked some other needed fixes.  Those issues were the only obvious problems.

When you are focused on one shiny problem, it is easy to overlook checking for other, unrelated ones.  I just went ahead and fixed the edit without opening the question in another tab.  I discovered later that the question was on-hold for a reason that didn't jump out in the review queue, and neither the proposed edit nor mine dealt with the hold issue.

I would like to propose an alternate (or additional), change:

**In the edit review queue, the question should display the same "(on hold)" label in the title that appears with the question on the main page and when opening the question in its own window.**

People get accustomed to seeing on-hold questions identified in that manner, and the edit review queue is the only place it is not displayed.  Lack of the label there leaves no indication that, in addition to reviewing the edit, the question should be double-checked for reasons it might be on hold.  That's important information that shouldn't be left out, and it is especially relevant in the edit review queue.

Comment: Displaying the hold status doesn't preclude that, but at least the edit will be done with knowledge of the status.  It can also work the other way--someone fixing some grammar will see that it's on hold and can also deal with the hold issue.

Comment: On that I agree, showing is knowing what is going on.  Has ANYone ever disagreed with that in the meta voting system? Has the feature request ever been declined?   Asking, to save me much time searching throughout , if you have already done that.

Comment: @Psycogeek: The feature request I cited in my question was posted a year ago and never went anywhere.  It did request something new, which would be a resource requirement and UI change.  I didn't spot a previous request to show the hold status in the title in the edit review window.  This doesn't sound like a major job, and would not be a UI change, given that it's already done for other screens and would just be making it consistent.

Comment: When doing a review one must view the actual question to determine if the edit is valid.